# Graphic novel with a man hallucinating with eyes floating out of his mouth

Tags: story-identification, novel, comics

I read a graphic novel once which I can only vaguely remember now. The main character was a man who was somehow connected to this other world (I can't remember if it was real or fantasy) and I do remember an illustration where he was hallucinating and eyeballs were floating out of his mouth.

I also remember this evil character that was sewn together and was in the process of sewing two characters together, making them into a conjoined, deformed human being.

I also remember another character (I think his name was Constantine,  I'm not sure) who was in this fantasy/alternate universe fighting a battle against some greater evil, and that the protagonist was somehow connected to it.

Comment: Do you remember how many years it's been? Maybe when you read it, or when it was published? If you haven't already can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: From 1988 to 2013, DC's Vertigo imprint published a monthly comic book titled *Hellblazer.* The star was named John Constantine. I never became a fan, but I know the series was full of graphic horror scenes (unlike, say, the typical family-friendly "Superman" comic book) and all sorts of strange and psychedelic things happened in it. You may very well be remembering a trade paperback collection of a story arc from that title. Since I've read almost none of the series, I can't pin it down with a nice specific "Answer," so I'm just leaving this suggestion in a comment.

Comment: This might also have been *The Books of Magic* in which John Constantine was a major character. I don't recall the sewing together scene, though.

Comment: @Edlothiad I believe I was 12 or 13 when I read this graphic novel, so I remember only vague details, like how the main character had a girlfriend with red hair, or how he jumped into the ocean with this other girl and made out with her.

Comment: @Lorendiac I looked up the Hellblazer comics, and I did not see a similar drawing style or similar plot to the graphic novel I read. I believe that Constantine was a part of it, though it has been a while and I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I distinctly remember there being a monster that had sewn another monster onto itself (similar to kuato in Total recall) and I remember the two people being sewn together only being shown by their eyes as they looked on in horror and pain. I also remember them going back to Constantine (if that's his name) as a warning. I believe the woman's name was Eve, but I'm not sure if the man was Adam. I still don't remmeber the protagonist's name or his GF, but I hope those additional clues help a bit.